# WPF-NotifyIcon Find Resource not working - Hardcodet.WPF.TaskbarNotification

Tags: c#, wpf

I have downloaded Hardcodet.WPF.TaskbarNotification added the code change in application start up as below.

```
   protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnStartup(e);
       //create the notifyicon (it's a resource declared in NotifyIconResources.xaml
      tb = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("MyNotifyIcon");
   }
```

Am getting error in FindResource as System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKey Not found exception.
I have tried of adding NotifyIcon class library in project and added the dll as reference. Still am getting ResourceReferenceKeyNotFound Exception. Can any one help. Thanks in advance.

Hi, I tried the following code. ResourceReferenceKey exception is resolved. But on notifyicon, double click is not working. Can any one help

```
public App()
    {
        this.StartupUri = new System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
        System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/app.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {           
        App app = new App();
        //var app = new HTM2.HTMAdmin.App();
        //app.InitApplication();            
        app.Run();
    }

    //public void InitApplication()
    //{
    //    ResourceDictionary resColl = Resources;

    //    notifyIcon = TryFindResource("NotifyIcon") as TaskbarIcon;
    //}

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        //create the notifyicon (it's a resource declared in NotifyIconResources.xaml
        notifyIcon = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("NotifyIcon");            

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Luckily for you, I had a similar struggle,
What you want to do is to use

```
tb = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("MyNotifyIcon");
```

After the startup event, in the *'MainWindow.xaml'* or however you call it,
personally, I have done this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private TaskbarIcon tb; //create as a field to easily access it later

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; //Hide the xaml screen
        //initialize NotifyIcon
        tb = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("MyNotifyIcon");
        tb.Icon = global::MY_ProjectRESX.Properties.Resources.eye1;
    }
}
```

And in another note, why are you working with the old version?
there is a new version called: *'WPF NotifyIcon'* which is very similar but more powerful in some situations and with a full and very helpful [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon-2#tutorial2) and project files.

Comment: Hi, What is PC_SmartStay ? Could you please help to find this and please explain in detail. As part of new version, am using the WPF NotifyIcon library from that tutorial in my code. Still giving the same error.

Comment: Hi, I tried the following code. It worked for me. But now on notify Icon, double click is not working. Are you having any idea.

Comment: @bharathshyamala I'm sorry about the tb.Icon, PC_SmartStay it's my personal project, I didn't notice that in the code, I will fix that, and about the double click, I don't know exactly why it is not working for you, it should work since we are not changing it but I do think that defining notifyIcon in 'app,.xaml' might cause it

Comment: okay. I have added NotifyIcon project and Sample project as reference in my project from WPF NotifyIcon tutorial. Now everthing is okay. Am doing some UI changes in main window and it moved to system tray.

Am not getting the latest window again. In showwindowcommand, the window is newly initialized.

I tried of adding static variables and modified the UI code in showwindowcommand. But double click functionality is not working. Do you have any idea.

Comment: Actually, I think it is because you initialize your main window again, try to use your current window, I'm pretty sure it will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add the ressources to the App.xaml. I was calling the `FindResource`command in the App.xaml.cs file.

```
<Application x:Class="MyNamespace.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- merge NotifyIcon and related stuff into the application -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="NotifyIconResources.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```